# HTML Class not working?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to change the text color in a `<p>` to gray. I thought doing something like `<p class="gray">content</p>` and `p.gray { color: #333333; }` would work but it's not doing anything. The color remains black. Help please?

**EDIT TO INCLUDE ENTIRE CODE**

HTML:

```
<!DOCTYPE html 
     PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Strict//EN"
     "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-strict.dtd">

<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">

<head>

<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>

<title>TITLE</title>

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="c/main.css?90" />

</head>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="divider">
  <h1 class="logo5">NAME</h1>
  <ul class="underlinemenu">
    <li><a href="index.html">HOME</a></li> 
    <li><a href="about.html">ABOUT</a></li>
    <li><a href="subscribe.html">SUBSCRIBE</a></li>
    <li><a href="faq.html">FAQ</a></li>
    <li><a href="contact.html">CONTACT</a></li>
    <li><a href="login.html">LOGIN</a></li>
  </ul>
  </div> <!-- end divider -->

  <div id="divider">
  <div class="article">
    <h2 class="header">HEADER</h2>
    <div class="content">
      <p class="gray">CONTENT</p>
      <p>CONTENT</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div> <!-- end divider -->

  <div id="divider">
  <div class="article">
    <h2 class="header">HEADER</h2>
    <div class="content">
      <p>CONTENT</p>
      <p>CONTENT</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div> <!-- end divider -->

  <div id="divider">
  <div class="article">
    <h2 class="header">HEADER</h2>
    <div class="content">
      <p>CONTENT</p>
    </div>
  </div>
  </div> <!-- end divider -->

  <div id="footer">
    <p class="copyright">COPYRIGHT</p>
  </div>
</div> <!-- end wrapper -->
</body>
</html>
```

CSS:

```
/*
    Name: Smashing HTML5
    Date: July 2009
    Description: Sample layout for HTML5 and CSS3 goodness.
    Version: 1.0
    Author: Enrique Ramírez
    Autor URI: http://enrique-ramirez.com
*/

/* Imports */
@import url("reset.css");
@import url("global-forms.css");

/***** Global *****/
/* Body */
    body {
        background: #FFFFFF;
        color: #000305;
        font-size: 87.5%; /* Base font size: 14px */
        font-family: 'Trebuchet MS', Trebuchet, 'Lucida Sans Unicode', 'Lucida Grande', 'Lucida Sans', Arial, sans-serif;
        line-height: 1.429;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
        text-align: left;
    }

/* Headings */
h2 {font-size: 1.571em} /* 22px */
h3 {font-size: 1.429em} /* 20px */
h4 {font-size: 1.286em} /* 18px */
h5 {font-size: 1.143em} /* 16px */
h6 {font-size: 1em} /* 14px */

h2, h3, h4, h5, h6 {
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 1.1;
    margin-bottom: .8em;
}

/* Anchors */
/*a {outline: 0;}
a img {border: 0px; text-decoration: none;}
a:link, a:visited {
    color: #C74350;
    padding: 0 1px;
    text-decoration: underline;
}
a:hover, a:active {
    background-color: #C74350;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px #333;
}*/

/* Paragraphs */
p {margin-bottom: 1.143em;}
* p:last-child {margin-bottom: 0;}

strong, b {font-weight: bold;}
em, i {font-style: italic;}

::-moz-selection {background: #F6CF74; color: #fff;}
::selection {background: #F6CF74; color: #fff;}

/* Lists */
ul {
    list-style: outside disc;
    margin: 1em 0 1.5em 1.5em;
}

ol {
    list-style: outside decimal;
    margin: 1em 0 1.5em 1.5em;
}

dl {margin: 0 0 1.5em 0;}
dt {font-weight: bold;}
dd {margin-left: 1.5em;}

/* Quotes */
blockquote {font-style: italic;}
cite {}

q {}

/* Tables */
table {margin: .5em auto 1.5em auto; width: 98%;}

    /* Thead */
    thead th {padding: .5em .4em; text-align: left;}
    thead td {}

    /* Tbody */
    tbody td {padding: .5em .4em;}
    tbody th {}

    tbody .alt td {}
    tbody .alt th {}

    /* Tfoot */
    tfoot th {}
    tfoot td {}


/* LAYOUT */
/* ----------------------------------------- */

div#wrapper {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 936px;
}

div#divider {
    border-bottom: 1px dotted #c5c5c5;
    margin: 0 0 10px 0;
    padding: 0 0 10px 0;
}

/*Credits: Dynamic Drive CSS Library */
/*URL: http://www.dynamicdrive.com/style/ */

.underlinemenu{
font-family: Delicious;
font-weight: bold;
width: 100%;
}

ul.underlinemenu {
padding: 6px 0 7px 0; /*6px should equal top padding of "ul li a" below, 7px should equal bottom padding + bottom border of "ul li a" below*/
margin: 0;
text-align: right; //set value to "left", "center", or "right"*/
}

ul.underlinemenu li{
display: inline;
}

ul.underlinemenu li a{
color: #FF0080;
padding: 6px 3px 4px 3px; /*top padding is 6px, bottom padding is 4px*/
margin-right: 20px; /*spacing between each menu link*/
text-decoration: none;
border-bottom: 1px dotted; /*bottom border is 3px*/
}

ul.underlinemenu li a:hover, ul.underlinemenu li a.selected{
color: #009ee8;
border-bottom-color: #009ee8;
}

p.copyright a{
color: #FF0080;
text-decoration: none;
}

p.copyright a:hover{
color: #009ee8;
}

/* embedded fonts */

@font-face {
font-family: Delicious;
src: url(fonts/Delicious-Heavy.otf)
}

.header {
font-family: Delicious;
}

.logo5 {
font-family: Delicious;
}

p.gray {
color: #333333;
}
```

I know it's a hacked up mess, sorry. I'm learning.

Comment: That should work. Please show the exact code you are using.

Comment: Eh it's a pretty big mess. Here give me a second I'll edit my question with the entire html & css.

Comment: are you declaring your style in the html document or in a separate CSS file? If in a separate file, are you linking/importing the CSS file in your html document's head element?

Comment: I'm linking yes, and I know it's linked correctly because everything else is working.

Comment: Try putting the style inline just to check if it works: `<p style="color: #333333">CONTENT</p>`. Also `#333333` may not be very noticeably different from black.

Comment: what is in `@import url("reset.css")` and `@import url("global-forms.css")`? Are they overriding anything?

Comment: It worked! I did `<p style="color: #FF0000">CONTENT</p>` (red) and it's... well... red! :) If this works why isn't my CSS working?

And nothing is in `reset.css` or `global-forms.css`, the files don't even exist.

Comment: @MW2000: I tested the exact HTML and CSS that you posted and they seem to work fine on both Firefox and Chrome.

Answer (score 4):

It should work fine. try more lighter color #666.

Comment: I agree. If you want to make sure, try a very different color, like yellow.

Comment: It doesn't, nice catch though. It works when I style the `<p>` inline like `<p style="color: #FF0000">CONTENT</p>` just not with my linked CSS.

Answer (score 2):

**QUICK FIX:** In your css file use '!important'. This will override the conflicting CSS you have unless you have used it in the first place.

```
p.gray { color: #333333 !important; }
```

**REAL FIX:** Was mentioned above. Use firebug (FireFox plugin) and inspect the element to see what CSS is affecting the element in question.

Comment: I tried adding !important as a quick fix but still no change. My original post's been appended with the entire code if that helps.

Answer (score 1):

This is where a tool like Firebug or Chrome's developer tools come in handy. Most likely, you have CSS that's at a later point in your CSS file that's overriding this style, or maybe you have some Javascript which is doing it.  It's hard to tell without a good web debugger.

If you use Firebug on Firefox, you can open up the HTML view and select your element, and it will show you *why* that element is styled the way it is.  From there, you can eliminate the problem.

**EDIT:  It works fine.  Seriously -- #333333 is a really dark color, almost indistinguishable from black on a white background.**

Comment: My class is at the very bottom, so shouldn't it override anything above?

And I use Google Chrome. Are the developer tools built in?

Comment: Yes, Chrome's dev tools are built in.  Where to look for them depends on your platform, but I highly recommend playing with it.

Comment: Will do I'm sure it's useful. In the mean time though can you help me out? I posted the entire code now. And inline styling seems to work, just not my linked CSS.

Answer (score 1):

Using ids and classes in parent elements can sometimes take precedence in confusing ways. To see if this is the issue, get very, very specific and try:

```
#wrapper #divider .article .content p.gray{
color:red;
}
```

Bright colors are good for testing.
If it now works you should probably read up on how ids and classes override each other when they conflict.

I looked over this article and it seems like a decent start: http://www.vanseodesign.com/css/css-specificity-inheritance-cascaade/

Comment: Nice suggestion but it didn't work :(. I even made sure my CSS wasn't cached.

Why do things never work right?

Comment: My bad, I shouldn't have put .header in there. I've edited to fix. Try it now?

Answer (score 1):

Could there be a typo in the CSS file somewhere that is causing the browser to ignore your p.gray definition?

Try putting the p.gray CSS higher up in the file, such as after the * p:last-child CSS, and see if that makes a difference.

Comment: +1, there's a mistyped comment in the CSS (`//set value to "left", "center", or "right"*/`) which might be causing the problem. Works for me on Firefox, but OP is using Chrome, which may be too strict. **Edit:** Works fine on Chrome too, don't know why it doesn't work for OP.

Answer (score 1):

You need to make sure your p.grey is before your normal p {} in your css code